# What should I do if I found a solution to a question I asked?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I asked a question, it's not very good and needs some editing, and the problem wasn't solved — but I found a workaround and don't really have time to edit the question to make it look good. Also, I don't want to delete it, because there were some useful comments and one answer. What should I do? Just leave it as is?

Comment: Did you consider posting your workaround as an answer?

Comment: @JeanneDark it's too unrelated to question, but yeah ig I could do it

Comment: @OleksiiHaponiuk Didn't mean to sound bad. What I'm trying to say is that it's worth putting effort in order to improve the post, for you and for future readers.

Comment: @OleksiiHaponiuk - Maroun actually gave you good advice - for all the time you'll spend in back-and-forth here and calling people trying to help "toxic", you could've edited the question and helped the community by making your post better.

Comment: Soooo, there was a misunderstanding, let's leave it at that already. _*Points at the "new user" banner*_

Comment: @Yatin - at the moment of the edit, the link only served to draw more eyes to the question, and the OP was becoming more and more frustrated as the question was drawing attention to itself. At the time, Dharman was already on the question - the link served nothing but further instigate the conflict - which I removed alongside OPs edit left out of frustration. I don't think the link is relevant anyways - there is nothing specific to the post. Frankly, what to do in such cases is explained well enough in the Q&A chain suggested by gnat above.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> but I found a workaround

It sounds like you might have something that could be valuable as an answer on that question.

This is especially nice for potential future readers. Nothing is more annoying that finding the exact question you're about to ask, with only a comment:

> *"Oh I found a workaround! - SomeUser, 4 years ago"*.

If at all possible, I'd suggest answering your own question.

Comment: [Who were you, DenverCoder9? *WHAT DID YOU SEE?!*](https://xkcd.com/979/)

Comment: [xkcd 979 explained](https://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/979:_Wisdom_of_the_Ancients)